# Put Row of range in variable (Long) if first occurrence cell contains today?

Tags: excel, vba

in my workbook Column `I` contains Dates.
I can get last Row easily by:

```
 Dim LastRow As Long
 LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
```

I need to put Row of that column in variable (Long) if first occurrence cell contains today.
actually , the expected code like this:

```
 Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("I" & FirstRow & ":I" & LastRow)
```

**Note:**  using `VBA AutoFilter` is not applicable on my workbook , Because it is protected and shared on the same time

[image]

Comment: What are you going to do with the range ?

Comment: You can easily find the row by using the **Match** function. Try this: `Application.Match(CLng(Date), Sheet1.Range("I:I"), 0)`. Change sheet accordingly (I would set a variable to the sheet and use that as it's better). The `CLng` converts the **Date** to a _Long_ number which can be matched against the dates in the search column. As long as the date exists in the column it will work. If not you will get an error which you will need to capture through error handling. I should point out this function will return the first position in the range it finds it in (aka row number)

Comment: @Simon: That's a great idea. It works even though the first two cells are merged. You should definitely post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, test the next simple code. All credit should go to @Simon, who clearly described what is to be done. I only put it in place, using a `Variant` (`mtch`) variable, able to be checked even if an error (in case of no any match) occurs:

Since your data in I:I does mean `Time` (something as `03.01.2022  21:27:37`), the range must be corrected for the `Date` `Long` value to be matched. Please, test the code:

```
Sub firstCellTest()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, firstCell As Long, lastCell As Long, rng As Range, mtch, arr
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastCell = sh.Range("I" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   Set rng = sh.Range("I1:I" & lastCell)
   arr = Evaluate("INDEX(int(" & rng.Address & "),0)") 'place in an array only the Date part of existing time
   mtch = Application.match(CLng(Date), arr, 0)
   If IsNumeric(mtch) Then
        firstCell = mtch
        Set rng = sh.Range("I" & firstCell, "I" & lastCell)
  Else
        MsgBox "Today date could not be found..."
  End If
  If Not rng Is Nothing Then Debug.Print rng.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: I know now why your edited code didn’t work with me.
To force the return of an array with `Evaluate`, I had to use `Index with int` as the following code:
`arr = Evaluate("INDEX(int(" & rng.Address & "),0)")`.  I found this answer on a similar issue here on ST.
I tried it and works correctly.

Comment: @Waleed What "didn't work" does mean? Do you receive an error, or what?

Comment: I thought you will update (the Edited code) with Adding `Index` ,to make it easier for anyone seek a similar request

Comment: @Waleed I still cannot understand why in the existing way it doesn't return the correct array. That's why I asked "what `didn't work` does mean"... Can you explain what is happening in your case? The code should work, as it is, in any excel version. It's a simple evaluation of a simple formula: `=int(I1)` (for the whole range), which should work in any environment. Why should I add something which, without further clarifications, it looks unnecessary? So, **how the code didn't work for you**?

Comment: `Didn't work` means that output of `Evaluate` function is wrong (with no error raised).
If you still remember, the wrong output happened on my work PC and my own laptop (you tried by using AnyDesk).
Anyhow, I found a similar issue [Link]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73877627/the-result-of-evaluate-on-a-range-is-incorrect)  , and the answer suggests to use `Index` To force the return of an array with Evaluate.
Then I tried on my case and I founded that your `Edited` codes starts to works correctly with me.
I just want to save time for anyone faced the same issue.

Comment: @Waleed I couldn't understand your comment because in my case it never happened to no return such an array, of course, using the code as in above updated answer. In fact, I will delete the first code, which it does not work as it should, anyhow... Now, I remotely connected to a computer in my office and tried the code on an Excel 2007 installation. It did not return the array as I thought! So, **only now I could understand what you meant**. Without that, I couldn't do anything. Like you know, if I do not understand what is to be done, I do nothing, only asking for clarifications... :) Thanks!

Comment: @Waleed Adapted the code in the suggested way, to make it working for any Excel version.

Answer (score 1):

### Reference a Range Using the Find Method

- This solution will find the first occurrence of today's date in a column and create a reference to the range from this cell to the bottom-most non-empty cell in the same column.
- The `RefTodaysRangeTEST` procedure illustrates how to use the `RefTodaysRange` function (the way to go).
- The `TodaysRange` procedure does the same thing without using a function yet cluttering your code.
- The `TodaysRangeDebugPrintStudy` procedure prints the range addresses at the various stages to the Immediate window (<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RefTodaysRangeTEST()

    Const fCellAddress = "A3"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range(fCellAddress)
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = RefTodaysRange(fCell)
    
    ' Continue, e.g.:
    If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Today's Range Address: " & trg.Address(0, 0)
    Else
        MsgBox "Today's Range Address: not available."
    End If

End Sub


Function RefTodaysRange( _
    FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim lCell As Range ' last (bottom-most) non-empty cell
    Dim fCell As Range ' first (top-most) cell containing today's date
    
    With FirstCell
        
        Dim crg As Range
        Set crg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
        Set lCell = crg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' no data
    
        Set crg = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
        Set fCell = crg.Find(Date, lCell, xlValues, xlWhole)
        If fCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' today's date not found
    
    End With
    
    Set RefTodaysRange = fCell.Resize(lCell.Row - fCell.Row + 1)

End Function


Sub TodaysRange()
    
    Const fCellAddress = "A3"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range(fCellAddress)
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = fCell.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - fCell.Row + 1)
    
    Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = crg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data from 'fCell' to the bottom
    
    Set crg = fCell.Resize(lCell.Row - fCell.Row + 1)
    
    Set fCell = crg.Find(Date, lCell, xlValues, xlWhole)
    If fCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' today's date not found
    
    Set crg = ws.Range(fCell, lCell)

End Sub

Sub TodaysRangeDebugPrintStudy()
    
    Const fCellAddress = "A3"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Debug.Print "Worksheet:    " & ws.Name
    
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range(fCellAddress)
    Debug.Print "First Cell:   " & fCell.Address(0, 0)
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = fCell.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - fCell.Row + 1)
    Debug.Print "Column Range: " & crg.Address(0, 0)
    
    Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = crg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data from 'fCell' to the bottom
    Debug.Print "Last Cell:    " & lCell.Address(0, 0)
    
    Set crg = fCell.Resize(lCell.Row - fCell.Row + 1)
    Debug.Print "Column Range: " & crg.Address(0, 0)
    
    Set fCell = crg.Find(Date, lCell, xlValues, xlWhole)
    If fCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' today's date not found
    Debug.Print "First Cell:   " & fCell.Address(0, 0)
    
    Set crg = ws.Range(fCell, lCell)
    Debug.Print "Column Range: " & crg.Address(0, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: it is not working , I changed  Const fCellAddress = "A3" to "i3". The final crg Range: i3:i7 , It should be  `i5:i7`

Comment: Which one did you try? 1, 3 or 4?

Comment: 4 and 3 tried `crg.Select` at end but no effect

Comment: The last sub will show you 7 lines of results if the cell was found. If not, there will be fewer lines. Also, the first sub, which you should actually use with the function, will show a message if it was are was not found. If it wasn't, then the date maybe not a date, but a string.

Comment: I tried 4 , the result in immediate window is `Column Range: I3:I7`. I also tried option 3 `Sub TodaysRange()` and I added `crg.Select` at end for test but no effect , I thinks the Sub exit before this line.

Comment: I checked again Range Column i and it is `formatted as date`

Comment: The 4th sub shows `3` lines with `Column Range`, so you obviously have fewer and the cell with today's date cannot be found. Today is `01/03/2022`. Note the year.

Comment: the format of Range is `[$-en-US]d-mmm-yyyy;@`. If you do not mind,I can share the sheet and send link for you here.

Comment: Try replacing `Date` with the formated text: `Format(Date, "[$-en-US]d-mmm-yyyy;@")` or just `Format(Date, "d-mmm-yy")`. It is surely related to the format.

Comment: I tried this code before Run of any sub   `Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("I3:I50")
    Rng.NumberFormat = "d-mmm-yy"
    Rng.value = Rng.value`  but unfortunately the same output in immediate window is `Column Range: I3:I7`