# The result of Evaluate (on a range) is incorrect

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this line of code and it works correctly `Range("S2:S7").Formula = "=LEN(E2)"`
But, when I changed it to Evaluate , I got incorrect result of Len function (always = 9) 
In advance thanks for your help.

```
Sub Evaluate_Test()
 
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("S2:S7")
    rng.value = Evaluate(Len(rng.Offset(0, -14).Address))
 
End Sub
```

Comment: In this case `Len` is the VBA [Len function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/len-function) and not the formula [LEN, LENB functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/len-lenb-functions-29236f94-cedc-429d-affd-b5e33d2c67cb). That's a difference because `Len` returns a number and then there is nothing to evaluate.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ ,It can Evaluate, Please see "Rory" comment

Comment: No, in your question there is nothing to evaluate. It is pure VBA. The VBA `Len` function cannot be evaluated only the `=LEN` formula function can be evaluated. You use the VBA function in your question but Rory uses the formula function! That's a difference.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ ,Is that means that `Evaluate` is used only with Worksheet functions and not pure vba functions?

Comment: Yes, almost correct: See [Application.Evaluate method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate#remarks) for what `Evaluate` can actually do. It does only work with Excel elements but not with VBA functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This working answer is fully credits to @Rory :
To force the return of an array, I had to use `Index` with `Len` as the following code:

```
Sub Evaluate_Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("S2:S7")
    rng.value = Evaluate("INDEX(LEN(" & rng.Offset(0, -14).Address & "),0)")      'This Works correctly
End Sub
```

Comment: `rng.Value = rng.Parent.Evaluate("=LEN(" & rng.Offset(0, -14).Address & ")")` works fine for me.

Comment: @Tim Williams , I tried, But all cells in in `rng` = value of Len(E2)

Answer (score 2):

Your current set-up is passing a string (in this case the address `$E$2:$E$7`) to `Len`.

Try instead

`Evaluate("LEN(" & rng.Offset(0, -14).Address & ")")`

Comment: I tried, But all cells in in `rng` = value of Len(E2)

Comment: To force the return of an array, you could use `Evaluate("INDEX(LEN(" & rng.Offset(0, -14).Address & "),0)")`

Comment: You probably want `rng.Parent.Evaluate("LEN(" & rng.Offset(0, -14).Address & ")")` if you want to be sure the formula is evaluated in the context of the sheet where `rng` is located.  Otherwise it will use the ActiveSheet, which may or may not be correct.

Comment: @Tim Williams ,It doesn't work. actually I took "Rory" comment and posted as a working answer

Comment: @Soma - it does work without INDEX()

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use the formula itself:

```vb
rng.Formula = "=LEN(E2)"
rng.Value = rng.Value
```

or

```
rng.Formula = ="=LEN(" & rng.Offset(0, -14).Address & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```vb
Sub Evaluate_Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D7")
    rng.Value = rng.Parent.Evaluate("=LEN(" & rng.Offset(0, -2).Address & ")")
End Sub
```

Input/result:

[image]

Comment: Sure you are correct. But I am afraid as it did not works on my PC, I am using Microsoft Office is 2016 and may be there is an issue with using `Evaluate` in this version.